# $\gcd(1000, 1000 - x)$ if $0 < x < 1000$, $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find $\gcd(1000, 1000 - x)$ if $0 < x < 1000$, $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x$ is coprime to $1000$.

Since $1000 > 1000 -x$, it follows from Euclidean Algorithm,

$$1000 = 1(1000 - x) + x$$

But I can't go much further.

Lets assume then, $\gcd(1000, 1000 - x) = y > 1$,

Then, $1000 - x | 1000$ and from Bezout's lemma,

$1000a + (1000 - x)b = y \implies 1000(a + b) = bx + y$

$$a + b = \frac{bx + y}{1000} = \frac{y}{1000} + b \frac{x}{1000} $$

But then, $y/1000$ isnt an integer and the same with $bx/1000$, contradiction to $a + b$?

I dont think this is correct, but I'll try?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the greatest common divisor of $1000$ and $1000-x$ divides their difference too, which is just $x$. But $1000$ and $x$ are coprime, so this GCD must be equal to $1$.

[Added] A more general statement is true: if $n\mid a$ and $n \mid b$ then $n\mid az+by$, where $x, y$ are integers. The proof is as follow: $a = n k_1$ and $b = n k_2$, because $n$ divides both of $a,b$. This means that $az+by = nk_1z+nk_2y = n(k_1z + k_2y)$ and clearly $n$ divides the expression in brackets.

Now set $a = 1000$, $b = 1000-x$, $z = 1$ and $y = -1$.

Comment: I don't understand why this correct answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ By the Euclidean algorithm $\,\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,a\!-\!b).\ $  Put $\ a=1000,\ b = 1000\!-\!x$